# Reading multiple Files with different columns and different row lengths

Tags: r

I have a number of .tsv files. Unfortunately, they have differences in two ways - a different number of rows (I want to `rbind` to deal with this) and some have an extra column (which I want to exclude on import). I also want to remove "_raw" from the file names and insert this into a column

My starting point has been:

```
filenames <- dir_ls("Data/", regexp = "raw")

names <- filenames %>%
  path_file() %>%
  path_ext_remove()

data_raw <- map(filenames, read_tsv) %>%
  set_names(names)
```

Comment: DaveArmstrong - thanks for fixing the question!

Comment: How do you identify which column you want to remove from each file? Do all files have the same columns besides this column you wish to remove?

Answer (score -1):

```
library(dplyr)

# Empty list to hold results
ll <- list()
# Target source files
fs <- list.files(pattern = ".tsv")

for(f in fs){
  # Read from file
  temp <- read_tsv(f)
  # Save modified filename as field value
  temp$file <- sub(pattern = "_raw.tsv", replacement = "", x = f)
  # Save within a list
  ll[[f]] <- temp
}

# Compile list elements into a two dimensional object (matrix or dataframe)
# Using bind_rows, you don't need to worry about all columns
# matching among input datasets.
do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, ll)
```

Comment: cheers @Skaqqs that is great. Is there a way I can remove "Data/" from the sub(pattern) at the same time?

Comment: Great! I'm just guessing here because I don't know what your actual filenames are, but something like this might work: `sub(pattern = "data/(.*)_raw.tsv", replacement = "\\1", x = f)`